# Where are the symbol and relocation tables located in an object file?

Tags: c, compilation, binary, reverse-engineering

I would like to write a script which extracts and modifies both the symbol and relocation tables in object files. How do I find out where those tables are located?

EDIT: I am currently examining ELF format binaries
EDIT2: I am using the gcc compiler

Comment: @ikegami Indeed! I am examining ELF format binaries

Comment: Sounds like something `objdump` could do

Comment: @ikegami `objdump -rt` can show the contents of each, but I want to know the locations and I can't seem to figure out how

Comment: [Start here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) and then follow the links in the References, Further Reading, and External Links sections for more details.

Comment: [ELF format specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#Specifications)  and at the command prompt: `man 5 elf`

Comment: Why don't you refer the .map file?

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD What is a .map file?

Comment: Refer [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199844/what-are-gcc-linker-map-files-used-for/36735943)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961649/gcc-how-to-create-a-mapfile-of-the-object-file). Useful to find the address of every variable and function. Mentioning which compiler and linker you are using could yield more specific results