# Is There Such A Thinig As a C# Application Link Map Or Something Equivalent?

Tags: c#, .net

Is is there a C# build construct available that would allow me to create a link map containing symbols and offsets? I need to debug an application that is throwing an exception when running scheduled out of Task Scheduler.

Here are some details of what is going on: I have developed a C# application on Windows 10 Workstation (non-server). I am trying to run this application on Windows Server 2012 R2, which, like the Windows 10 system, has .net framework 4.5.1 installed.

The application runs with no known errors on the development workstation, whether it is run installed or out of Visual Studio 2012.

However, the application will not run at its scheduled time out of Windows Task Scheduler. This is the error  ***0xE0434352*** -- I have been reading SuperUser and stackOverflow posts about this error -- and the Windows application event log shows an exception has occurred.

However, the offsets in the application event log are not a lot of help without having a map of the executable.

Is creating a link map or equivalent possible?

Here is a link to one [description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199844/what-are-gcc-linker-map-files-used-for) of a linker map for gcc.

Comment: It might be useful to explain what link map is, or link to the project-page.

Comment: There is no project page for this application. You get a link map, or at least you used to, when compiling C or C++. It shows the symbols in the application, the application's starting address (virtual) after the loader loads it, and the offsets from that virtual starting address. OP now has a link to a linker map description.

Comment: No possibility to add some logging that would give you more information?

Comment: `However, the offsets in the application event log are not a lot of help without having a map of the executable.` What "offsets"? C# doesn't deal with raw memory addresses, so I'm not even sure what you think you're seeing. Post one of the event log entries.

Comment: C/C++ don't deal with raw memory either. They deal with a virtual starting point and offsets. The offsets can help you track down code to the line usually.

Comment: The task scheduler has a number of differences from a normal environment. Things like mapped drives, for example, might not be available, or it might not be running as the user account and with the permissions you expect. I know you might have the permissions to even test this, but are you able to run the application while logged into the server interactively?

Comment: Also, be aware that Server 2012 R2 is now fully **end of life**. That means it no longer receives updates -- **not even critical security patches**. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it. Don't take this too hard... I still have two such servers in my own environment that missed their migration targets, so it happens. But it shouldn't just be "business as usual", and moving to an actively supported environment should be job #1 here (my two servers will be fixed by mid-June).  _You might even find this fixes your issue._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in .Net the assemblies are [self-describing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/metadata-and-self-describing-components). A debug database file is useful, but not necessary to describe the objects and how the code is structured. So I would not think a link map are relevant for .net assemblies.

You might want to take a look at [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy), this is a combined de-compiler, debugger and assembly editor. It is often useful when trying to debug errors. It is however limited to managed code, so it will probably be less useful if the error is in native code.